# JAVA Arrays - Need somebody to explain what this code does?

Tags: java

```
int temp; 
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length/2; i++) {
    temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i];
    numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i] = temp;
```

So this is code in one of my labs but I don't understand it.

So first you declare int temp, but why? Shouldn't you declare a temp int array?

Then the second line is a loop that goes through the index and you /2 because you don't actually need to go through all values if you switch half, you switched all of them.

I don't understand the next two lines at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write a few test cases and find out.

Comment: Step through it in a debugger and see what it is doing.

Comment: `temp` (which is used for swapping elements of the array) should probably be declared in the first line of the `for` loop and no it shouldn't an array.

Answer (score 1):

Carefully step through the inside of the loop a couple times:

```
temp = numbers[i]; 
numbers[i] = numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i]; 
numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i] = temp
```

On your first pass i is 0

so start with an array like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

if temp=numbers[0] then temp will be 1.  numbers.length will be 5, so numbers.length-1-i will be 4.  numbers[4] is 5.  after you have done each line, repeat with i=1 then i=2.  Examine your array when you are done (it will change).

just keep on going like that.  It's better to figure it out for yourself than to be handed answers--much more fun :)

Answer (score 0):

(1) You declare int temp to store the value of variables that are being swapped in the array, so when you overwrite one of the array elements, you still have the variable value.  You don't need to use an entire array for this.

(2) The code you don't understand swaps the array values at numbers[i] and numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i], using temp as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

All this code does is reverse an array.  It goes all the way to array.length/2 (other wise if it went to length it would swap, then swap back doing nothing).

The temp doesn't need to be an array because it's just a variable to hold on to old values while the swap is happening.

The final two lines of the code is where the swap actually happens.

So if you provide input of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} it will output {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}.

If you look at when i =0:

numbers[0] = 1, numbers[4] = 5,

temp will become 1, then numbers[0] will become 5, then numbers[4] will become the value of temp (1).

So after that first iteration of the loop, your array will look like this:

{5, 2, 3, 4, 1}

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry too much about the declaration.  Let's focus on the lines you don't understand at all.  The three lines inside the loop are as follows:

```
temp = numbers[i];
```

This puts the value of the ith element of the array into temp (so we can get to it later).

```
numbers[i] = numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i];
```

This puts the value of the ith element from the end into the ith element.

```
numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i] = temp;
```

This puts the original value of the ith element into the ith element from the end.

That is, we iterate over the first half of the array, swapping elements with the opposite elements from the second half of the array.  In other words, we are reversing the array.